# Finding last line's last to one position and appending content via Bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to add xyz abc string in particular file in last line's last to one position.

For example, I have mentioned sample file which has last line programs, there could be other programs which needs to be added via bash script. I can use sed for replacing but programs values is dynamic so might be code should be like finding last line, last to one minus position -> append xyz -> save?

## Tried code:

```
sed '$s/$/'"$(paste -sd, 'msft ibm')"'/' ${SampleFile}
```

## Sample file:

```
ldap_userdn="uid=google,cn=admins"
programs="ie firefox google"
```

## Expected file:

```
ldap_userdn="uid=google,cn=admins"
programs="ie firefox google msft ibm"
```

Please note that values are added with double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just replace the last `"` with your programs :

```
$ cat > f
ldap_userdn="uid=google,cn=admins"
programs="ie firefox google"

$ sed '$s/"$/ msft ibm"/' f
ldap_userdn="uid=google,cn=admins"
programs="ie firefox google msft ibm"
```

Comment: $ sed -e '$s/"$/ msft ibm"/' f # -e was missed. Thanks fredtantini!